# Was Sun's father planning to have Jin murdered in America?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

**Warning: Major spoilers for *Lost* follow**

In the final season of *Lost*, in the afterlife timeline, Jin is traveling to America with Sun as her bodyguard while she shops in Los Angeles. He has another assignment from Sun's father for the trip: he is to deliver a watch and $25,000 to a man. We learn as the plot develops that Jin is having an affair with Sun, Sun's father has learned of the affair, and the watch and $25,000 are payment for the man who receives them to murder Jin as punishment for sleeping with the boss's daughter.

Now in the living timeline that begins in Season 1, Jin and Sun are married and traveling to America so Jin can deliver the watch to someone there. There is no mention of $25,000, but it is never explicitly stated that he wasn't *also* delivering money. We later learn that Sun's father does not respect Jin and did not think much of him as a match for his daughter. In addition, when Sun has an affair, he loses more respect for Jin. My question is: was it ever explicitly stated on the show that Sun's father had sent Jin to America for him to be murdered in the actual living timeline? If not, has JJ Abrams or anyone else associated with the show ever stated that the idea was that Jin had been heading to his death on Oceanic 815 before it crashed?

Comment: I don't believe it is ever fully addressed, but "The LOST Experience" gave way to theories that Paik Industries was tied to the Hanso Foundation and ultimately to Dharma Initiative and the Island. But outside of that there is no indication that Jin would of been murdered or that Paik knew the plane would crash...Warning!! There are SPOILERS at the following link! https://lostpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Woo-Jung_Paik

Comment: That would seem unlikely because Jin was Sun's father's muscle.  He was sent to beat people up who crossed Sun's father.

Comment: @Darth: That's interesting. Note that Paik's knowledge of whether Oceanic 815 would crash is not necessarily relevant, but I would say it's unlikely he would want to let his daughter die or throw away that expensive watch and so it's unlikely he knew. Johnny: Jin is hardly Paik's only muscle. Crime lords kill their underlings all the time on TV and movies.

Comment: @ruffdove Exactly, that's the only reason why I think it wouldn't make sense in terms of that, but just some secondary food 4 thought, it would rely on Farady's debate tying into multiple iterations of the timeline (whatever happened happened vs people r variables) & what he may or may not know/believe about that. In addition Sun takes a big interest in company later & confronts Charles Widmore, but we don't ever really know what Sun may have all learned in that time frame, it's never put 2 use in final season. Many Q's remain w semi-moot answers depending on how one interprets LOST's mythos.